# How can I keep showing a Js var in HTML after route changes?

Tags: javascript

I'm bad with Javascript and would like your help!
Hi, I'm building a Rails application and would like to add some features related to geoloction. For that I get the current location of the user with JS and then print it with HTML.

As you guys will see, my code runs every time the page loads, but when my routes change, for example: /about, /settings, /events, it simply disappear and I have to load the page again to print the HTML element.

```
/* CURRENT LOCATION */
function geolocationSuccess(position) {
  var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
  var longitude = position.coords.longitude;

  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var latlng = {lat: latitude, lng: longitude};

  geocoder.geocode({'location': latlng}, function(results, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      if (results[0]){
        var user_address = results[0].formatted_address;
        document.getElementById("current_location").innerHTML = user_address;
      }else {
        console.log('No results found for these coords.');
      }
    }else {
      console.log('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
    }
  });
}

function geolocationError() {
  console.log("please enable location for this feature to work!");
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  if ("geolocation" in navigator) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geolocationSuccess, geolocationError);
  } else {
    alert("Geolocation not supported!");
  }
});
```

How can I have the current location printed on this element in all my application routes?
I wouldn't like to request this information every time.
Maybe a cookie? I don't know...
or request just once every some time
What do you guys recommend? Please help me :)

Comment: You can use Javascript's Localstorage, or if you are leveraging Server side languages, or a database, you might store it in Session Variables, such that it is loaded each time a page is loaded. Personally, I like to offload as much to the client, so i would prefer local storage if you are keeping instances on a per machine basis.  It would be better for a DB if it is going to be a script which is on a per USER instance

Answer (score 1):

You can use `localStorage` for this purpose: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

`localStorage` allows you to save data between browser sessions and windows.

An example usage might be:

```
   ...
   // Somewhere in geocode request callback
   localStorage.setItem('user_address', results[0].formatted_address)

   ...

   // Somewhere in your render code
   document.getElementById("current_location").innerHTML = 
     localStorage.getItem('user_address')

   ...
```